# Disable geolocation box on browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, safari, geolocation

I need to disable the geolocation box on browser (all browser) using javascript. It is possible? When users land on my page the box is showing and i need to disable it in some case (for example in specific page only). Thanks for any helps

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d0XL.png

Comment: This box appears if the website asks for the location. So if you don't want it to appear, don't ask for the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask for the location, it will be shown (for user privacy and security). If you don't use location on your site then don't ask for the location